# How can I pause the polling behavior of Kafka Consumers?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to stop polling for a specific topic at a specific time.

- spring-boot 2.X
- spring-kafka 2.5.5
- Kafka version 2.5.1

For example, even if a message comes in to the TEST topic partition, the message is piled up in the partition from 00 to 01, and there is no consumption.

After 01 o'clock, I want to consume the message again on the TEST topic.

How to pause and resume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean to control the lifecycle of the listener containers; you can stop and start them according to whatever conditions you desire.

You can also configure them to be stopped until you explicitly start them.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle.

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "myContainer", topics = "myTopic", autoStartup = "false")
public void listen(...) { ... }
```

and

```java
@Autowired
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

...

    this.registry.getListenerContainer("myContainer").start();

...
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look and leave a comment if i have any questions.